# How to deploy flask virtualenv into production

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I developed a flask app running on virtualenv, how do I deploy it into production? I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6, cannot use docker.
The server has cgi and wsgi setup. Python 2.7.

I know using the pip install -r requirements.txt, but how do I get the virtualenv to persist on production once my session is terminated?

I am using source x../venv/bin/activate

export FLASK_APP=myapp.py

flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8082

and this will allow me to access myurl:8082

How do I present a way for other users once I terminate session?

Comment: Tried one of [deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/)?

Comment: @phd yes, I did. but I want to deploy virtualenv, that will help me to avoid install requirements on the main system. I am not allowed to alter versions of libs on the system.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#working-with-virtual-environments

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using a  `requirements.txt` file in Python.  Using `$ pip freeze > requirements.txt` can build that file with what pip has installed in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

In your current `virtualenv`, do:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In the production environment, install and activate `virtualenv`, and then do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current virtual environment, do this:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create `requirements.txt` file on your local machine.

Copy the `requirements.txt` file to your production server from your current local machine.
Finally,
In the production environment create the virtual environment using `virtualenv` and then do this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix-like host running systemd, you can create and start a service, which takes your virtual environment as a configuration parameter.  [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-falcon-web-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) is a walk-through for a similar tech. stack.